# Find all words in a string that start with the $ sign in Python

Tags: python, regex, dollar-sign

How can I extract all words in a string that start with the $ sign? For example in the string

```
This $string is an $example
```

I want to extract the words `$string` and `$example`.

I tried with this regex `\b[$]\S*` but it works fine only if I use a normal character rather than dollar.

Comment: `\w` is better than `\S` if you are searching for words (and don't want commas/points/semicolons/quotes/… included too).

Comment: Why do you want to extract those words?  This looks suspiciously like some kind of string-substitution language, in which case you really should just use [`string.Template`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings), since it's already implemented for you, and already supports exactly this syntax.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
>>> [word for word in mystring.split() if word.startswith('$')]
['$string', '$example']
```

Comment: Use `word.startswith('$')`. It's more readable (and it handles empty words).

Comment: This is actually the better solution so far.

Comment: @user1515248 - yeah, I like to avoid regex, when at all possible ;)

Comment: omg this was so much simpler.. i was looking for solutions to extract urls, and my string isn't too messed up and this works for it. Now i need to look for what to do about any punctuation marks at end and I'm set.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with your expr is that `\b` doesn't match between a space and a `$`. If you remove it, everything works:

```
z = 'This $string is an $example'
import re
print re.findall(r'[$]\S*', z) # ['$string', '$example']
```

To avoid matching `words$like$this`, add a lookbehind assertion:

```
z = 'This $string is an $example and this$not'
import re
print re.findall(r'(?<=\W)[$]\S*', z) # ['$string', '$example']
```

Comment: It'll match `$$words` too though, won't it?

Comment: @Martijn, yes, a couple of problems with this one. Anyways, non-regex solution is better in this case.

Comment: That won't match at the very beginning of the string.  I would use a *negative* lookbehind: `(?<!\w)`.

Answer (score 6):

The `\b` escape matches at word boundaries, but the $ sign is not considered part of word you can match. Match on the start or spaces instead:

```
re.compile(r'(?:^|\s)(\$\w+)')
```

I've used a backslash escape for the dollar here instead of a character class, and the `\w+` word character class with a minimum of 1 character to better reflect your intent.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> dollaredwords = re.compile(r'(?:^|\s)(\$\w+)')
>>> dollaredwords.search('Here is an $example for you!')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100882a80>
```

Comment: @thg435: quite right, discovered this too :-P Corrected it to address the *real* problem.

Comment: Just add parenthesis `(?:^|\s)(\$\w+)` and you will not have the space added to the match. Cheers!

Comment: @drewk: Yup; but I still think the non-regex solution is the better here.

Answer (score 2):

Several approaches, depending on what you want define as a 'word' and if all are delineated by spaces:

```
>>> s='This $string is an $example $second$example'

>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\$\w+',s)
['$string', '$example', '$second']

>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\s)\$\S+',s)
['$string', '$example', '$second$example']

>>> re.findall(r'\$\w+',s)
['$string', '$example', '$second', '$example']
```

If you might have a 'word' at the beginning of a line:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|\s)(\$\w+)','$string is an $example $second$example')
['$string', '$example', '$second']
```

Comment: This'll match `word$with$embedded$dollars`.

Comment: It won't match the first word in a string, e.g. '$first other words'

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I did qualify as "delineated by spaces' and have added a match group that handles words at the beginning of a line too...

Comment: Which is the same as my solution, with the same problem: the preceding space is now part of the matched string. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using regex:

z = 'This $string is an $example to$ get o$n$l$y words $sta$rts with $'

print(re.findall(r'\s$[\S]*', z))

Output: [' $string', ' $example', ' $sta$rts', ' $']